# Submit Button Cant Pass variable on Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new on CI

I have try to create Update Form on CI. but when I Click the Submit Button, it nothing happen.

the **Controller script**

```
function save_company()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['EDIT']))
        {

            $data = array(
                          'ID'  => $this->input->post('ID'),
                          'NIP' => $this->input->post('NIP'),
                          'nama' => $this->input->post('NAMA'),
                          'golongan' => $this->input->post('GOLONGAN'),

                    );
                    $this->load->model('company_model');
                    $hasil=$this->company_model->edit_data_employee($data);
                    if($hasil)
                    {
                        echo "Simpan berhasil";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Simpan data gagal <br>";
                    }   
                    echo anchor('company_controller','Back');
        }//end isset

    }//end fucnntion
```

and **The model script**

```
public function edit_data_employee($data)
    {
        $this->db->where('ID',$data['ID']);
        $hasil=$this->db->update('employee',$data);

        return $hasil;

    }
```

The **View Script**

```
<?php form_open('company_controller/save_company');?>
<table align='center' border='1' width="500">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Edit Data</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>NIP</td>
        <?php $field1=array('name' => 'NIP','size'=>'20','value'=>$datacompany[0]->NIP); ?>
        <td><?php echo form_input($field1);?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nama</td>
        <?php $field2=array('name' => 'NAMA','size'=>'20','value'=>$datacompany[0]->nama); ?>
        <td><?php echo form_input($field2);?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Golongan</td>
        <?php $field3=array('name' => 'GOLONGAN','size'=>'20','value'=>$datacompany[0]->golongan); ?>
        <td><?php echo form_input($field3);?></td>

        <?php $id=array('name' => 'ID','size'=>'20','value'=>$datacompany[0]->ID);?>
        <?php form_hidden($id); ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><?php echo form_submit('EDIT','Edit');?>
    </td>

</table>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Can Anyone Helpme to Fix This?

Im very appreciated your answer.

Thanks

Comment: You can't submit the form or you can't update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss to echo your form_open

```
<?php form_open('company_controller/save_company');?>
```

to

```
<?php echo form_open('company_controller/save_company');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php form_open(site_url().'company_controller/save_company');?>
```

or

```
<?php form_open(base_url().'index.php/company_controller/save_company');?>
```